# TypeError: can't convert nil into String with DateTime ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method which returns the date into UTC format

```
DateTime.strptime(json_doc["assetFields"]["originalAirDate"], "%Y-%m-%d").iso8601
```

But this would return error as above if `json_doc["assetFields"]["originalAirDate"] is nil`.

I need to use the .try() method in ruby so that it will not throw the exception.

I am not sure how it can be achieved with Datetime.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting a default date when `nil` works for you:

```
default_date = "2014-01-01"
DateTime.strptime(json_doc["assetFields"]["originalAirDate"] || default_date, "%Y-%m-%d").iso8601
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should prepare a value before throwing it in there:

```
date = json_doc["assetFields"].try(:[], "originalAirDate")

date ? Date.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").iso8601 : ''
```

Comment: okay.. then for Time.parse(json_doc["startTime"]).utc I should use if condition. Can it be done with try() also as above

Comment: You shouldn't parse something that isn't there, so you don't need `try`. Just don't parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline rescue, to get a default value in case of an exception:

```
DateTime.strptime(json_doc["my_date_field"], "%Y-%m-%d").iso8601 rescue ''
```